# Determine ODBC database driver from TADOConnection object?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ms-access, odbc, ado

Using Delphi 7 with ADO objects, is it possible to determine the ODBC database driver from the TADOConnection object? So detect whether it is MS-Access or SQL Server or Oracle etc.

[image]

The program connects to a database by just using the name of an ODBC data source, and I want to determine whether that database is an MS-Access database or SQL Server. I want to do this because MS-Access and SQL Server use different SQL function names to cast an integer to a string.

The application builds an SQL string which retrieves the VERSION of some configuration objects. It works for SQL server using `cast()`, but I also want to support MS-Access which uses `CStr()`:

```
SELECT NAME + '_' + CAST(VERSION as varchar) as OBJECT_NAME FROM ANALYSIS // SQL Server
SELECT NAME + '_' + CStr(VERSION) as OBJECT_NAME FROM ANALYSIS // MS-Access
```

I've tried looking at the TADOConnection.Provider but that is `MSDASQL.1` in both cases.

```
if (myqry.Connection.Provider = 'MSDASQL.1') then
  strSQL := strSQL + 'cast(' + myfieldname + ' as varchar)' // always goes here..
else
  strSQL := strSQL + 'CStr(' + myfieldname + ')'; // ..never to here
```

I've looked at all the TADOConnection properties, but I'm starting to suspect it's not possible. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODBC is designed to abstract away the implementation details of the server.  You can [use ODBC specific syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that will be translated to a statement of the appropriate SQL flavour for the server.  Here you can substitute :

```sql
... { fn CONVERT( VERSION, SQL_VARCHAR ) } AS OBJECT_NAME FROM ANALYSIS
```

These substitutions are known as [ODBC Escape Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and can be substituted in queries where there are vendor-specific syntax differences.